# Add string "Advanced help" into transifex

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, editor, localization, transifex

In the editor there is a string `Advanced help`:

> [image: editor]

But there is no such string in the transifex. Previously used string was `advanced help` (key `7a3845cdfc05fdb11c21d4d2250fcad3`).

Could you add new string into transifex, so we will be able to translate it?

Comment: This string was also just added. Might want to consider self-answering this one too.